# Spring Batch retry-policy, and skip-policy issue

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have following step in batch job.

```
    <batch:step id="parse-step">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="xmlCommonReader"
                         processor="xmlCommonProcessor"
                         writer="xmlCommonWriter"
                         commit-interval="1">
                <batch:skip-policy>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy" scope="step"/>
                </batch:skip-policy>
                <batch:retry-policy>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.NeverRetryPolicy" scope="step"/>
                </batch:retry-policy>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="file-failed-step"/>
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="file-success-step"/>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="parseStepExecutionListener"/>
            <batch:listener ref="parseStepSkipListener"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
```

When some exception throws, i catch him in **parseStepSkipListener** and log in database.

I expect the following behavior:

1. Job Started
2. Executing previous steps
3. Start execution of **parse-step**
4. Read item
5. Process item
6. Write

   1. Ooooops, exception.
   2. Catch exception, log in database, go to next chunk(Read, Process, Write).
7. Continue execute other steps.
8. Finish job.

But actually i get following behavior:

1. Job Started
2. Executing previous steps
3. Start execution of **parse-step**
4. Read item
5. Process item
6. Write

   1. Ooooops, exception.
   2. Process item
   3. Write item

      1. Ooooops, exception.
      2. Catch exception, log in database, go to next chunk(Read, Process, Write).
7. Continue execute other steps.
8. Finish job.

So, one chunk of data try to process and write **two** times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In few words:

This happens because when an error occured in write step SB doesn't know which object caused the exception so a rollback is performed and every single item of last uncommited chunk is processed/writed again as a mini-chunk to detect which object was the cause of main write error.
You can read more (with diagrams) [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-3-skip-and-retry/)

Comment: But i add in configuration retry-policy: org.springframework.retry.policy.NeverRetryPolicy, i think, this should prevent batch from double processing of the same chunk/item?

Comment: I think retry means "try again to write chunk if a particular set of exceptions occured" (retry '6.Write point' according to retry logic) and not "don't try to detect which item was the source of writing error" (skip 6.1 and following points)

Comment: Ok, i will try play with skip and retry logic.

Comment: is there any chance to be aware being in the "rollback mini-chunk processing"? In my processor I already write some status information to db. If this is executed the second time it will fail because the status information has already been written.